# How to get an AsyncTask to cancel itself when the activity finishes

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm developing a ListActivity that has a bunch of information displayed in each items of the list.
Since gathering the data to display in each entry of the list (thumbnail from the SD card and counts from the DB) is time intensive I thought about using AsyncTasks to relieve the main thread from the load and allow the user to scroll through the list really fast without lagging.

I thought about using the tag of the views in my entry to cancel the AsyncTasks of the entries that are reused after scrolling off the screen.
something like:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    [...]
    MyAsyncTask t (MyAsyncTask) myImageView.getTag();
    if (t != null) {
        t.cancel(true);
        t = null;
    }
    t = new MyAsyncTask();
    myImageView.setTag(t);
    t.execute();
    [...]
}
```

That part should work but my problem is when the activity finishes or the user changes orientation. I would rather avoid keeping an array or a hash map of my AsyncTasks just to be able to cancel them all in onPause or onStop.
From the reading I did on the web the AsyncTasks will continue running in the background after the orientation changes or the activity finishes and even worst it will keep the activity alive preventing it from being garbage collected (which is definitely not what I want.)

Any ideas or suggestions on how I could do this ?
Should I use something else than AsyncTasks ?

Comment: The keeping a list of all your tasks might solve this problem, why don't you like this approach?

Comment: It just seems like there should be a better solution.

Comment: What I had in mind (and described in my question actually doesn't have the expected effect as the tasks don't stop when I call `cancel(true)` and I end up with a `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException` on the line where I try to `execute()` the next task after playing around with the list and once the pool of threads for AsyncTasks is full. I know the idea is to check for `isCancelled()` periodically from `doInBackground(Object[])` to finish the task as early as possible but in my case it's not possible since I just call one function and don't have access to its source. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider replacing array of `AsyncTask`s with one `AsyncTask`. [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) could help here.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I only load my items one at a time instead of loading them all as they appear ? I'm not sure I understand your answer.